# Postgres create trigger function to copy value from one column to another before allowing insert

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger function in Postgres 13 that, before an insert or update operation is done, will copy values from two columns to two other columns.

Before an update/insert operation my table `test.run_conf` looks like this:

| hostname | run_config_current | run_config_current_hash | run_config_last | run_config_last_hash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| switch01 | old_txt_str | 32314322 |  |  |

When an update/insert occurs I want the value from `run_config_current` copied to `run_config_last` and `run_config_current_hash` copied to `run_config_last_hash`. Then allow the update/insert operation to occur against column `run_config_current` - after which the trigger function will recalculate the value for `run_config_current_hash`.

For testing, I run the following query to insert new data into the column `run_config_current`:

```
INSERT INTO test.run_conf (hostname, run_config_current) VALUES ('switch01', 'new_txt_str' )
ON CONFLICT (hostname) DO UPDATE SET run_config_current = excluded.run_config_current
```

However what happens is the table `test.run_conf` gets updated as follows - the new value gets inserted into both columns `run_config_current` and `run_config_last`:

| hostname | run_config_current | run_config_current_hash | run_config_last | run_config_last_hash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| switch01 | new_txt_str | 47173234 | new_txt_str | 32314322 |

The trigger and function I have in place now that is not working properly is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.run_conf_hash_gen_func()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    SET SCHEMA 'test'
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        NEW.run_config_last := NEW.run_config_current;
        NEW.run_config_last_hash := NEW.run_config_current_hash;
        NEW.run_config_current_hash := MD5(NEW.run_config_current);
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER run_conf_hash_gen_trig
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on test.run_conf
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.run_conf_hash_gen_func();
```

Please help me to understand why my code seems to be copying the new value for `run_config_current` into `run_config_last`. Thank you!

Comment: Because you need the `OLD.run_config_current` when doing the `UPDATE`. This means that in the trigger function you will need to distinguish between and `INSERT` or `UPDATE` as `INSERT` does not have `OLD` values.  See `TG_OP` here [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: Turns out in Postgres 11+ `OLD` for `INSERT` is set to `NULL` so you do not have to guard against the pre-11 behavior of `OLD` being unassigned in an `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. My issue was that I was referencing the `NEW` var as reference for the values to assign. Since the vars `NEW` and `OLD` are set at trigger execution, but before changes, my old code was using the values I sent via my INSERT/UPDATE statement as what to assign to my _last columns.

Here is my updated trigger function that works as expected. I commented out the old/bad lines and the new lines underneath are what is working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.run_conf_hash_gen_func()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    SET SCHEMA 'test'
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
    BEGIN
        -- NEW.run_config_last := NEW.run_config_current;
        NEW.run_config_last := OLD.run_config_current;
        -- NEW.run_config_last_hash := NEW.run_config_current_hash;
        NEW.run_config_last_hash := OLD.run_config_current_hash;
        NEW.run_config_current_hash := MD5(NEW.run_config_current);
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$
```

Comment: That will not work when the action is an `INSERT` as there is no `OLD` row in an insert.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yep and that is actually the desired behavior. If its an INSERT, its a brand new entry for the device in question, so there is no "last" comparison to make. On the next run of my code, it will re-fetch configurations from devices and then do an UPDATE where an entry already exists, causing those other 2 columns to populate.

Comment: When I said it will not work I meant just that, the `INSERT` will fail totally. Pretty sure that is not what you want.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Hmm. My OP includes the insertion query my code will use with an "ON CONFICT" clause. Running it several times it is working as expected. I also run simple test INSERTs using unique hostnames and those work as well.

Comment: Hmm, it turns out I need to keep up with the docs. In Postgres 10- 'This variable is unassigned in statement-level triggers and for INSERT operations.' and in 11+ 'This variable is null in statement-level triggers and for INSERT operations.'. Habit has me coding for the pre-11 behavior. Probably still will, but your code is good.